# Confusion over how to refactor and tidy up this script

Tags: javascript

I have a large JS file which i'll post below.  Basically, there is an issue I am experiencing with it which I need solving but I feel I need to refactor and tidy it all up on route to finding the problem.  My issue is, i'm not too sure what are my best options with how to go about tidying it up and potentially splitting it into more manageable chunks and how each chunk interacts with each other.

Can anyone provide any suggestions on how I could go about this?

I know I can move each part out into separate files etc but i'm not too sure how to get each file to interact with others in the same way as them all being in one file.

Some suggestions and pointers would go a long way in helping me to improve my script.

Thanks.

My script:

```
import URI from 'urijs'
import Handlebars from 'handlebars'
import InfiniteScroll from 'infinite-scroll'
import Flickity from 'flickity'
import { getOffsetTop } from './get-offset-top.js'
import MicroModal from 'micromodal'
import SlimSelect from 'slim-select'

// Define global variables
let infScroll = false
let infiniteScrollEnabled = false
let object = false
let selector = false
let url = false

function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout
    return function () {
        var context = this, args = arguments
        var later = function () {
            timeout = null
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args)
        }
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout
        clearTimeout(timeout)
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait)
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args)
    }
}



function toggleViewMoreButton() {
    if (document.querySelector('.pagination')) {
        document.querySelector('.view-more-button').style.display = 'inline-flex'
    } else {
        document.querySelector('.view-more-button').style.display = 'none'
    }
}



function refreshModals() {
    // Use whatever selector you're using for MicroModal triggers.
    const modalTrigger = 'data-micromodal-trigger'

    // Get all triggers.
    const modalTriggers = document.querySelectorAll(`[${modalTrigger}]`)

    modalTriggers.forEach(trigger => {
        // Get the attribute to save.
        const triggerElement = trigger.getAttribute(modalTrigger)

        // Remove the attribute briefly to clear memory/existing modals.
        trigger.removeAttribute(modalTrigger)

        // Immediately add it back.
        trigger.setAttribute(modalTrigger, triggerElement)

        // Re-initialize.
        MicroModal.init()
    })
}



function doInfiniteScroll() {
    if (document.querySelector(`.paginator--${object}s .next_page a`)) {
        let gridElement = document.querySelector(`.${object}-grid`)
        let requestPath = `.paginator--${object}s .next_page a`

        infScroll = new InfiniteScroll(gridElement, {
            path: requestPath,
            append: `.${object}-top-level`,
            scrollThreshold: false,
            status: '.page-load-status',
            button: '.view-more-button',
            history: false
        })

        infScroll.on('append', (response, path, items) => {
            // Refresh Modals
            refreshModals()

            // Manually push URL to the Turbolinks history
            Turbo.navigator.history.push(new URL(path));

            console.log(path)
        })

        infScroll.on('request', function (path) {
            console.log(path)
        })

        infiniteScrollEnabled = true
    }
}



function endInfiniteScroll() {
    if (infiniteScrollEnabled) {
        infScroll.destroy()

        infiniteScrollEnabled = false
    }
}



function updateGrid(url) {
    fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            let template = document.getElementById('park-and-coaster-grid-template').innerHTML
            let templateScript = Handlebars.compile(template)
            let html = templateScript(data)

            document.querySelector('.wacky-worm').innerHTML = html

            // Re enable InfiniteScroll
            doInfiniteScroll()

            // Refresh Modals
            refreshModals()

            // Show or Hide View More button
            toggleViewMoreButton()
        })

    // Add current filter settings to URL history (Remove page query if on first page)
    let queries = url.search(true)
    if (queries.page == 1) {
        url.removeSearch('page')
    }

    url.suffix('')

    Turbo.navigator.history.push(new URL(url));
}









document.addEventListener("turbo:load", function (e) {
    // Figure out whether we are dealing with Parks or Coasters
    if (document.body.classList.contains('parks-index') || document.body.classList.contains('coasters-index') || document.body.classList.contains('rides-index')) {
        object = document.querySelector('.wacky-worm').getAttribute('data-object')

        if (document.querySelector('.item-coaster_attributes')) {
            const slim_select = new SlimSelect({
                select: '.item-coaster_attributes',
                placeholder: 'All attributes',
                allowDeselectOption: true
            });
        }

        doInfiniteScroll()

        toggleViewMoreButton()

        // Pagination
        document.querySelector('.wacky-worm').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            if (e.target.matches('.pagination li a')) {
                e.preventDefault()

                endInfiniteScroll()

                url = new URI(e.target.getAttribute('href'))
                // params = url.search(true)
                url.suffix('json')

                updateGrid(url)
            }
        })

        // If a year is selected then show the "New in <year>" checkbox automatically
        var url = new URI();
        let queries = url.search(true)
        if (queries.page == 1) {
            url.removeSearch('page')
        }

        if (queries.ridden_in) {
            let year = queries.ridden_in
            let new_in_ridden_in_year_element = document.querySelector('.item-new-in-ridden-in-year')

            new_in_ridden_in_year_element.querySelector('.update-year-here').innerHTML = 'New in ' + year
            new_in_ridden_in_year_element.style.visibility = 'visible'
        }





        // Order
        document.querySelector('select.item-sort').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
            let selected = e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].value
            url = new URI()

            endInfiniteScroll()

            url.removeQuery('sort')
            url.addQuery('sort', selected)
            url.removeSearch('page')
            url.addQuery('page', 1)
            url.suffix('json')

            updateGrid(url)
        })




        // Material
        selector = 'select.item-material'
        if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
            document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach(radio => {
                radio.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
                    let selected = e.target.value
                    url = new URI()

                    endInfiniteScroll()

                    if (selected == 'all') {
                        url.removeSearch('material')
                        url.suffix('json')

                        updateGrid(url)
                    } else {
                        url.removeSearch('material')
                        url.addQuery('material', selected)
                        url.removeSearch('page')
                        url.addQuery('page', 1)
                        url.suffix('json')

                        updateGrid(url)
                    }
                })
            })
        }



        // Milestones
        selector = '[type="checkbox"][name="milestones"]'
        if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
            document.querySelector(selector).addEventListener('change', (e) => {
                url = new URI()

                endInfiniteScroll()

                if (e.target.checked) {
                    url.removeSearch('milestones')
                    url.addQuery('milestones', 1)
                    url.removeSearch('page')
                    url.addQuery('page', 1)
                    url.suffix('json')

                    updateGrid(url)
                } else {
                    url.removeSearch('milestones')
                    url.removeSearch('page')
                    url.addQuery('page', 1)
                    url.suffix('json')

                    updateGrid(url)
                }
            })
        }



        // Soundtracks
        selector = '[type="checkbox"][name="soundtracks"]'
        if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
            document.querySelector(selector).addEventListener('change', (e) => {
                url = new URI()

                endInfiniteScroll()

                if (e.target.checked) {
                    url.removeSearch('soundtracks')
                    url.addQuery('soundtracks', 1)
                    url.removeSearch('page')
                    url.addQuery('page', 1)
                    url.suffix('json')

                    updateGrid(url)
                } else {
                    url.removeSearch('soundtracks')
                    url.removeSearch('page')
                    url.addQuery('page', 1)
                    url.suffix('json')

                    updateGrid(url)
                }
            })
        }



        // Reverse
        selector = '[type="checkbox"][name="reverse"]'
        if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
            document.querySelector(selector).addEventListener('change', (e) => {
                url = new URI()

                endInfiniteScroll()

                if (e.target.checked) {
                    url.removeSearch('reverse')
                    url.addQuery('reverse', 1)
                    url.removeSearch('page')
                    url.addQuery('page', 1)
                    url.suffix('json')

                    updateGrid(url)
                } else {
                    url.removeSearch('reverse')
                    url.removeSearch('page')
                    url.addQuery('page', 1)
                    url.suffix('json')

                    updateGrid(url)
                }
            })
        }



        // Countries
        selector = 'select.item-countries'
        if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
            document.querySelector(selector).addEventListener('change', (e) => {
                let selected = e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].value
                url = new URI()

                endInfiniteScroll()

                if (selected == 'all') {
                    url.removeSearch('country')
                    url.suffix('json')

                    updateGrid(url)
                } else {
                    url.removeSearch('country')
                    url.addQuery('country', selected)
                    url.removeSearch('page')
                    url.addQuery('page', 1)
                    url.suffix('json')

                    updateGrid(url)
                }
            })
        }



        // Parks
        selector = 'select.item-parks'
        if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
            document.querySelector(selector).addEventListener('change', (e) => {
                let selected = e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].value
                url = new URI()

                endInfiniteScroll()

                if (selected == 'all') {
                    url.removeSearch('park')
                    url.suffix('json')

                    updateGrid(url)
                } else {
                    url.removeSearch('park')
                    url.addQuery('park', selected)
                    url.removeSearch('page')
                    url.addQuery('page', 1)
                    url.suffix('json')

                    updateGrid(url)
                }
            })
        }



        // Manufacturers
        selector = 'select.item-manufacturers'
        if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
            document.querySelector(selector).addEventListener('change', (e) => {
                let selected = e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].value
                url = new URI()

                endInfiniteScroll()

                if (selected == 'all') {
                    url.removeSearch('manufacturer')
                    url.suffix('json')

                    updateGrid(url)
                } else {
                    url.removeSearch('manufacturer')
                    url.addQuery('manufacturer', selected)
                    url.removeSearch('page')
                    url.addQuery('page', 1)
                    url.suffix('json')

                    updateGrid(url)
                }
            })
        }



        // Park Chains
        selector = 'select.item-parkchains'
        if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
            document.querySelector(selector).addEventListener('change', (e) => {
                let selected = e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].value
                url = new URI()

                endInfiniteScroll()

                if (selected == 'all') {
                    url.removeSearch('parkchain')
                    url.suffix('json')

                    updateGrid(url)
                } else {
                    url.removeSearch('parkchain')
                    url.addQuery('parkchain', selected)
                    url.removeSearch('page')
                    url.addQuery('page', 1)
                    url.suffix('json')

                    updateGrid(url)
                }
            })
        }



        // Letter
        selector = '[type="radio"][name="letter"]'
        if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
            document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach(radio => {
                radio.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
                    let selected = e.target.value
                    url = new URI()

                    endInfiniteScroll()

                    if (selected == 'all') {
                        url.removeSearch('letter')
                        url.suffix('json')

                        updateGrid(url)
                    } else {
                        url.removeSearch('letter')
                        url.addQuery('letter', selected)
                        url.removeSearch('page')
                        url.addQuery('page', 1)
                        url.suffix('json')

                        updateGrid(url)
                    }
                })
            })
        }



        // Ridden in Year
        selector = 'select.item-ridden-in'
        if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
            document.querySelector(selector).addEventListener('change', (e) => {
                let selected = e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].value
                url = new URI()

                let new_in_ridden_in_year_element = document.querySelector('.item-new-in-ridden-in-year')

                // Set New in RIY Checkbox back to unchecked
                new_in_ridden_in_year_element.querySelector('[type="checkbox"]').checked = false

                endInfiniteScroll()

                url.removeQuery('new_in_riy')

                if (selected == 'all') {
                    new_in_ridden_in_year_element.style.visibility = 'hidden'

                    url.removeQuery('ridden_in')
                    url.suffix('json')

                    updateGrid(url)
                    console.log(url)
                } else {
                    new_in_ridden_in_year_element.style.visibility = 'visible'
                    new_in_ridden_in_year_element.querySelector('.update-year-here').innerHTML = 'New in ' + selected

                    url.removeQuery('ridden_in')
                    url.addQuery('ridden_in', selected)
                    url.removeQuery('page')
                    url.addQuery('page', 1)
                    url.suffix('json')

                    updateGrid(url)
                    console.log(url)
                }
            })
        }



        // New in Ridden in Year
        selector = '[type="checkbox"][name="new_in_riy"]'
        if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
            document.querySelector(selector).addEventListener('change', (e) => {
                url = new URI()

                endInfiniteScroll()

                if (e.target.checked) {
                    url.removeQuery('new_in_riy')
                    url.addQuery('new_in_riy', 1)
                    url.removeQuery('page')
                    url.addQuery('page', 1)
                    url.suffix('json')

                    updateGrid(url)
                } else {
                    url.removeQuery('new_in_riy')
                    url.removeQuery('page')
                    url.addQuery('page', 1)
                    url.suffix('json')

                    updateGrid(url)
                }
            })
        }

        // Coaster Styles
        selector = 'select.item-coaster_styles'
        if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
            document.querySelector(selector).addEventListener('change', (e) => {
                let selected = e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].value
                url = new URI()

                endInfiniteScroll()

                if (selected == 'all') {
                    url.removeSearch('coaster_styles')
                    url.suffix('json')

                    updateGrid(url)
                } else {
                    url.removeSearch('coaster_styles')
                    url.addQuery('coaster_styles', selected)
                    url.removeSearch('page')
                    url.addQuery('page', 1)
                    url.suffix('json')

                    updateGrid(url)
                }
            })
        }

        // Coaster Attributes
        selector = 'select.item-coaster_attributes'
        if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
            document.querySelector(selector).addEventListener('change', (e) => {
                // let selected = e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].value

                // Convert all of the options to an array
                // Then, get an array of only the options that are selected
                // Then, get an array of the selected option values
                let selected = Array.from(document.querySelector(selector).options).filter(function (option) {
                    return option.selected;
                }).map(function (option) {
                    return option.value;
                })

                selected = selected.join('|');

                url = new URI()

                endInfiniteScroll()

                if (selected == '') {
                    url.removeSearch('coaster_attributes')
                    url.suffix('json')

                    updateGrid(url)
                } else {
                    url.removeSearch('coaster_attributes')
                    url.addQuery('coaster_attributes', selected)
                    url.removeSearch('page')
                    url.addQuery('page', 1)
                    url.suffix('json')

                    updateGrid(url)
                }
            })
        }
    }
})
```

UPDATE:

I have this code in my main file:

```
export let infScroll = false
export let infiniteScrollEnabled = false

// Enable Infinite Scroll on grid items
if (!(infiniteScrollEnabled)) {
  startInfiniteScroll()
}
```

My startInfiniteScroll file is looking like this:

```
import InfiniteScroll from 'infinite-scroll'
import { object } from '../park-and-coaster-filters'
import { infScroll } from '../park-and-coaster-filters'
import { infiniteScrollEnabled } from '../park-and-coaster-filters'

export default function startInfiniteScroll() {
    console.log('start startInfiniteScroll')

    console.log(object)

    infScroll = new InfiniteScroll(`.${object}-grid`, {
        path: '.next_page a',
        append: `.${object}-top-level`,
        scrollThreshold: false,
        status: '.page-load-status',
        button: '.view-more-button',
        history: 'push'
    })

    console.log('end startInfiniteScroll')

    infiniteScrollEnabled = true
}
```

Basically, when running this I am getting an error in my console stating:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property infScroll of # which
> has only a getter
> at startInfiniteScroll

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to help refactoring code without proper knowledge about the entire code base. That said, I have some helpful tips on how you can improve your code:

- The `selector =` blocks are the same and should be written as a function.
- As a general rule: If you're writing the same code many times over, it belongs in a function.
- Try and split up your code into smaller functions. Each function should do only one thing. This also makes it easier to debug and manage.
- Write comments. You can use block comments to describe each functions' purpose, parameters, and return value:

```js
/**
 * Multiplies a number by two.
 * @param {Number} val - Number to be doubled
 * @return {Number} The number multiplied by two
 */
function double(val) {
  return val * 2
}
```

Here's a wonderful [article about using block comments](https://blog.shhdharmen.me/comments-usage-and-best-practices-in-javascript)

- Consider learning TypeScript as it helps you debug the code as you write it.

Hopefully this will help you make your code better from here on out.
Cheers!

---

### Edit

If you wish to move part of your code into different files, you have to use `export...import`.

```js
// utilityFunctions.js

export function double (val) {
  return val * 2
}
```

Import this function in your main script

```js
// index.js

import { double } from './utilityFunctions'

console.log(double(2))
// returns 4
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  It's not really splitting up into functions where I need assistance, even though that's exactly what I need to do.  It's more, how to split up over multiple files and how imports and exports work and how the files inter-relate etc. That confuses me.

Comment: Use `export default function double() {...}` in one file and `import double from './doubleFunctionFile.js'` in the file where you wish to use it.

Comment: Hi!  I'm working through my refactoring of this and it's going well but have hit an issue.  I will make an update at the end of my OP if you'd be ok with taking a look?  I'll go update it now...

Comment: Just updated my OP with a follow-up question as mentioned above.

Comment: You're not focusing on one particular problem as is the intention with SO questions. There's a ton of information about export/import freely available so seeing you import three times from the same lib, makes it look like you haven't even tried. Do some research and split this thread into multiple, separate questions. Keep up the good work buddy :)